# Contradictory error when using MobileAds in an Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, google-mobile-ads

I am somewhat confused by an error showing up in an Android app, where I want to use `MobileAds`.

Here is the Kotlin code:

```
val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
adView.loadAd(adRequest)
```

The AndroidManifest.xml file contains these three lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And these are the errors I get:

```
Missing permissions required by BaseAdView.loadAd: android.permission.INTERNET
Missing permissions required by FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

Is there anyone out there who has an idea of what is going on?
Any relevant tip or explanation would be more than welcome.

Just in case this is the complete AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="me.soft.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".WorldExposureActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:parentActivityName=".ShopDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXX" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-1234567890012345~1234567890"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".ShopMapActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_shop_map"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ShopDetailActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please Update your whole manifest.xml

Comment: Update? Do you mean "upload"?

Comment: I just edited the post for that, please take a look.

Comment: Did you initialize your mobile ads in your main/entry activity?

Comment: Yes I do MobileAds.initialize() in each activity where it is used.